# json4s JValue scala classTag works wrong

Tags: scala, json4s, classtag

In my code, I use `classTag[JValue]` want to get **org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue** ,
but actually it returns **org.json4s.JsonAST$JValue**, it is strange ! why there is the **$**?
 I am new guy use scala ,could someone answer me ? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name you use to refer to a class/method/etc. in your code and the name it has in bytecode produced by the compiler doesn't have to be the same. Scala compiler needs to be more of this name-mangling than the Java compiler, but this specific case is same for both.

The reason is that inner classes don't really exist on JVM: they are normal classes which have an additional field containing the outer instance. The JVM name of the class looks like `<outer_class>$<inner_class>`.

In Scala and Java, `$` in a name generally indicates it's mangled in some way (though it *is* a legal character for programmers to use as well).

Comment: thanks very much for your answer! i think i probably get the cause, but what i want in this situation is to get the normal classTag not the **$**, is there any way to fix or avoid it ?  thanks again

Comment: This _is_ the normal `ClassTag` (or rather the way it's printed with `toString`). If you want the class _name_ in the form you want, `replace("$", ".")` will work for this case. Handling all name mangling would be more difficult.

Comment: thanks , what i have done same as you say use `replace("$", ".")`, but it is not really pretty good, anyway  thanks for you answer